# How to block currency switcher for gift card page in magento2

Tags: php, magento, magento2, currency, mage

I am working on a Magento 2 website. I have installed Mageworx giftcard in magento2 and it's working fine. Currency switcher is also working fine.

My problem is the client wants to have the same denominations in gift card page. For example, we have US$20,US$30,US$50...however, if the user selects CAD currency then it shows as CA$26.33, CA$39.50,CA$65.83 like that.
Gift Card. Currency conversion to CAD doesn’t work for gift card amounts. Can we have same denominations as USD for CAD. i.e. we sell a $20 USD card or if currency is switched to CAD it’s a $20 CAD gift card?

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Mageworx giftcard acts as a new product type `mageworx_giftcards`. In order to achieve the requested feature, you can use multiple stores (preferably website) option in Magento.

To do this, follow below steps.

1. Create separate stores (preferably website) for USD and for CAD.
2. Change the product attribute `price` scope to store view from global.
3. Set gift card price per store view, means 20USD for USD store/website and 20CAD for CAD store/website.

NOTE: You should test the given suggestion on a separate staging instance before giving it a try on live site as this could create some issues if not followed properly.